# Git: Diff tool to view entire file's changes on one screen (or zoom out)

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

Is it possible to "zoom out" far enough to view an entire file's diff using a Git difftool? I would like to view all changes to a file within one screenshot. Is this possible?

I tried using `meld` and `kdiff3`, but I could not find a "zoom out" feature for either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using plain old `git diff` if you "zoom out" in your terminal.  Be sure to enable color in the terminal for git by:

```
git config --global color.ui auto
```

Then do the usual `git diff myfile` or whatever.  In some terminals, zoom is like a web browser: Ctrl-- and Ctrl-=.

In kdiff3 and probably meld, there should be a font size somewhere in the preferences too, but I don't have either in front of me to test it.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of shrinking font size to zoom out. I'm using meld and it works great. Thanks!